# pg-promise helpers.update not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I am unable to get the [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update) method working. I am almost 100% certain that it is something simple I am overlooking. 
Below are the columns in the table involved in the code:

- `user_social_profile_id`
- `user_id`
- `user_social_profile_platform`
- `user_social_profile_link`

Below is my definition for the `ColumnSet`. (Note I added some spacing that is NOT in my actual code. I just hate having to scroll those windows.)

```
const usersSocialProfiles = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  [ 
    'user_id', 
    'user_social_profile_platform',
    'user_social_profile_link'
  ],
  {table: 'users_social_profiles'}
);
const usersSocialProfilesUpdate = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  [ 
    '?user_social_profile_id',
    '?user_id',
    'user_social_profile_platform',
    'user_social_profile_link'
  ],
  {table:'users_social_profiles'}
);
```

Then a function to toggle between which `ColumnSet` I want to use

```
var pgpConstantSet = function(setName){
  if(setName === "usersSocialProfiles")
  {
    return usersSocialProfiles; 
  }
  if(setName === "updateUsersSocialProfiles")
  {
    return usersSocialProfilesUpdate;
  }
}
```

The attempt to use the ColumnSet

```
  var profiles = await pgp.helpers.update(userData.socialProfiles, 
  pgConstantSet("usersSocialProfiles"))+ 
  " WHERE t.user_social_profile_id=v.user_social_profile_id";
  console.log(profiles);

  return res.status(201).end();
```

And what the console.log(profiles) prints

> UPDATE "users_social_profiles" AS "t" SET 
>   "user_id"="v"."user_id","user_social_profile_platform"="v"."user_social_profile_platform","user_social_profile_link"="v"."user_social_profile_link"
>   FROM (VALUES(51,'facebook','http:/w.sefvfaboklink.com')) AS
>   "v"("user_id","user_social_profile_platform","user_social_profile_link")
>   WHERE t.user_social_profile_id=v.user_social_profile_id PATCH
>   /api/users 201 55.858 ms - -

I should note that I used the other `ColumnSet` I defined for inserts worked like a charm. I really appreciate anyone who got here. I know this is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All types and methods in the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) namespace are for generating queries, which you confuse for executing them.

In your code you only generate the query, but never execute it. You should remove the `await` before `helpers.update` call, as query generation is synchronous, and use one of [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) methods to execute the query. The latter is asynchronous ;)

---

On another note, a better way for your example to declare `usersSocialProfilesUpdate`:

```
const usersSocialProfilesUpdate = usersSocialProfiles.merge([
    '?user_social_profile_id',
    '?user_id'
  ]);
```

See methods [merge](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#merge) and [extend](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#extend) that help avoiding re-declaration of the same columns.